# filter nested children sqlalchemy to arbitrary depth

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a complex model. Let's say it contains 100 entities, all of which are related to each other in some way. Some are many to many, some are one to one, some are many to one, and so on.

These entities all have `start` and `end` timestamps indicating valid time ranges. When loading these entities via query, I wish to populate the relationship fields only with entities that have `start` and `end` stamps wrapping a given timestamp: for example `datetime.now()`, or yesterday, or whenever.

I'll define two models here for example, but assume there are a vast number of others:

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

class Role(base):
    __tablename__ = 'Role'

    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('User.uid'))
    user = relationship(User, backref=backref('Role')
    start = Column(DateTime, default=func.current_timestamp())
    end = Column(DateTime))
```

Now, I want to return entities via restful endpoints in flask. So, a `get` might look something like this in flask:

```
def get(self, uid=None) -> Tuple[Dict, int]:
    query = User.query
    if uid:
        query.filter_by(uid=uid)
    return create_response(
        query.all()
        200
    )
```

Now, I want to restrict the `Role` entities returned as children to the `User` returned by the above query. Obviously, this could easily be done by just extending the `query` to filter the Roles. The problem comes when this scales up. Consider 100 nested levels of child relationships. Now consider restful endpoints providing a `get` for any one of them. It would be practically impossible to write out a `query` to properly filter every different level of child.

My desired solution was to define loading behavior on each entity, making everything composable. For example:

```
class User(base):
    __tablename__ = 'User'

    role = relationship("Role",
                     primaryjoin="and_(Role.start<={desired_timestamp} "
                                 "Role.end>={desired_timestamp})")
```

The problem, of course, is that we don't know our `desired_timestamp` at class definition time as it is passed at runtime. I have thought of some hacks for this such as redefining everything during every runtime, but I'm not happy with them. Does anyone have some insight as to the "right" way to do something like this?

Comment: My thought is to subclass `User` inside `get()`, defining the `role` relationship on the subclass so that you can specify the textual primary join once you know what the desired time stamp is. Then query the subclass. Disclaimer is I’m not at a computer so haven’t tried it out!

Comment: If doing tihs, one would have to define the relationships in a similar manner for the other 100 child relationships, and do this for the get on every resource (of which there is one for every entity, so 100 again). It's a similar problem to just defining a complex query in the get.

Comment: But your ‘desired behavior’ shows you want to define the relationship on the entity. This would be no different it would just be done in the `get()` func. Anyway, surely with that many relationships to define on entities you’d find a way to generalize the class creation perhaps using `type()` with 3 args? And also have a more general `get()` rather than defining 100 routes that all do a similar thing? At least that’s the road I’d be trying to go down, but then again I might not understand the scope of you problem.